# What is meant by ''set' object is not subscriptable' and how do i remove it from my code

Tags: python-3.x, list, cs50

Question: implement a program that prompts the user for a date, anno Domini, in month-day-year order, formatted like 9/8/1636 or September 8, 1636. Then output that same date in YYYY-MM-DD format. If the user’s input is not a valid date in either format, prompt the user again. Assume that every month has no more than 31 days; no need to validate whether a month has 28, 29, 30, or 31 days.

My Solution: Comments are before each part in the code. On line 44, (marked in aesteriks (*)) it shows "**TYPEERROR:  'set' is not subscriptable** when i input the date : **January 12, 1234.** I dont know what it means or what I'm doing wrong. What that part is supposed to do is store the month's number from the list and update the variable `month`.

Here's my code:

```
#define list
months = { "January", "1"
    "February", "2"
    "March","3"
    "April","4"
    "May","5"
    "June","6"
    "July","7"
    "August","8"
    "September","9"
    "October","10"
    "November","11"
    "December""12"
}

#input date
date_input = input("Date: ")


#loop
while True:
    try:
        #MONTH---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if "/" in date_input:
            month, day, year = date_input.split("/")
            month = month
            break
        elif " " in date_input and "," in date_input:
            month, day, year = date_input.split(" ")
            day = day.replace(",", "")
            break
        else:
            date_input = input("Date: ")
    except ValueError:
        pass

while True:
    try:
        #MONTH------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if month.isalpha():
            for item in months:
                if month == item:
                    **month = (f"{int(months[item]):02}")**
                    break
        elif month.isdigit():
            month = int(month)
            if month > 0 and month < 13:
                if month > 0 and month < 10:
                    month = (f"{int(month):02}")
                    break
        else:
            date_input = input("Date: ")
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

while True:
    try:
        #DAY---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if int(day) > 0 and int(day) < 32:
            if int(day) > 0 and int(day) < 10:
                day = (f"{int(day):02}")
            day = int(day)
            break
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(year, "-", month, "-", day, sep="")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
months = { "January", "1"
    "February", "2"
    "March","3"
    "April","4"
    "May","5"
    "June","6"
    "July","7"
    "August","8"
    "September","9"
    "October","10"
    "November","11"
    "December""12"
}
```

is a `set`, not `dict`. May be you want

```
months = { "January": "1",
    "February": "2",
    "March": "3",
    "April": "4",
    "May": "5",
    "June": "6",
    "July": "7",
    "August": "8",
    "September": "9",
    "October": "10",
    "November": "11",
    "December":"12"
}
```